# Create sublass instance from ancestor

Tags: scala

i am quite new in Scala. Have class named 'Document' and a few classes, like 'Doc1' and 'Doc2' which are children of Document. So:

```
abstract class Document(id: Int, xmlString: String) {
// make some operations and create an instance of subtype
}
case class Doc1 extends Document {
// some subclass specific methods
}
case class Doc2 extends Document {
// some subclass specific methods
}
```

**Would like to run Document constructor and as a result, create an instance of Doc1 or Doc2 conditionally due to passed paramethers**. Shall i add some auxiliary constructors in 'Document' class?

Any idea welcome.

Comment: The answer is **yes**. Why didn't you just tied? Also it is weird when you call constructor and resulting value have other type.

Comment: Would like to create a general class with a few general-used methods. One of the paramether will be xmlString and would like to infer a document type based on this variable and create an instance of particular class. Doc1 and Doc will have different methods.

Comment: Types (`Doc1` or `Doc2`) must be established at compile-time. Values (`"doc1"`, etc.) are known at run-time. Perhaps the safest option is to return `Either[Doc1,Doc2]` and then use methods like `.fold()` to unwrap the results.

Comment: Do you want the result to be of _type_ `Doc1` or `Doc2` or you want the type to be `Document` but with a specified concrete implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best practice is to use [companion object/singleton object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html):

```
abstract class Document { ... }
object Document {
  def apply(docType: String) = {
     if (docType == "doc1") {
         Doc1()
     } else {
         Doc2()
     }
  }
}
```

and the usage of it:

```
val document1 = Document("doc1")
```

Of course, it's just a simple example - you can change the `docType` to sealed class and check the type by pattern matching.

- Update - by @crater2150 comment - you can use the `apply` instead of different function name, so you will write `Document("doc1")` instead of `Document.someFunctionName("doc1")`

Comment: For constructor-like methods it's also common to name the method `apply`, so you can write `Document("doc1")` without mentioning the method name.

Comment: Your code has typos and doesn't really do what's requested. What is the type of `document1`? It's _not_ `Doc1`. It would have to be cast to `Doc1` in order to access `Doc1` methods.

Comment: @jwvh `document1` is of type `Document`, but its concrete type is `Doc1`. anyway, it's preferred to do pattern matching on the type, not casting.

Comment: Right. The _concrete_ type is `Doc1` but it is _not_ `Doc1`. It _should_ be safe to cast it `.asInstanceOf[Doc1]` but that's not a practice that I'd accept in _my_ code.